# Deleting a Folder from a Zip file

Tags: excel, vba, zip

**I am trying to Delete a Folder from the Zip file.**

**So My file structure is like:**

[image]

**Inside First:**

[image]

I tried to use the code here [Deleting Files from A Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804279/5720144) By Siddharth Rout, But it only Moves the files, apparently the folder becomes empty, ***but isn't deleted from the Zip***.

**Code:**

```
Sub del()


Dim oApp As Object
Dim fl As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each fl In oApp.Namespace("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\test\first.zip\first").Items
    'Path to a folder inside the Zip
        oApp.Namespace("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\test\Dump").MoveHere (fl.path)
    Next

End Sub
```

Apparently it moves all the files to the folder Dump, but the folder named `Second` stays intact in the Zip. Though all the files from second are also moved.

I can use the command `Kill` & `RmDir` afterwards to delete the moved files and Folder. But how to make the Second Folder Vanish from Zip.

**Note:**

- I don't mean to Move all the files from Zip, It's just the testing condition to keep the code short.
- *I am not looking for a Workaround to Unzip the file, delete the folder and Re-zip everything.*
- Let me know if any other information is Required.

Comment: Do you wan to remove the folder "first" or the "Second"?

Comment: I want to remove Folder `Second` from First.  [Sample Zip File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11Mjs3uCjvAzrbiBHNaBSAm5pI7BQFSJA)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627865/vbs-delete-folder-from-zipped-folder

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. It says it can't be done without 3rd Party App. Unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: @SMeaden ...How to delete the folder ? Files can be deleted and the way to do that is in the Link In the Question.

Comment: @mikku stop removing the Excel VBA tag. It bumps all the questions to the top.

Comment: Ohh .. Okay @Andreas .. i though anyway they have to be removed.

Comment: That will be done automatic when/if it happens. The heta thread says it's a two month thing, a year ago....

Comment: Yeah .. I thought I can so some of them.. Anyways, i will stop it it's creating a Problem. :) @Andreas

Comment: @Mikku It can be done without 3rd party tools. Just not without unpacking and rebuilding the archive.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ... But as you can see in the Below answer by TinMan, and it is able to delete the Folder with one command line, only thing to figure out is how to suppress the Windows Warning that pops up when you try and delete the folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to delete the folder.

> ```
> CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\test\first.zip\first\second").Self.Verbs.Item(4).DoIt
> ```

As GSerb pointed out it may be better to use `InvokeVerb)"Delete"` to delete the folder.

> ```
>  CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\test\first.zip\first\second").Self.InvokeVerb ("Delete")
> ```

I have not been able to suppress the file deletion conformation dialog.
[image]

---

So using `.Self.Verbs.Item(4)` we can access the Right Click Options starting with 0.

**Demo:**

[image]

### Addendum

My final working solution was to copy the contents of the Xip file to a temp folder, delete the sub folder, delete the original zip file, create a new zip file, and copy the remaining items to the new zip file.

**Usage:**

> ```
>   DeleteZipSubDirectory "E:\first.zip","\first\second"
> ```

```
Sub DeleteZipSubDirectory(ZipFile As Variant, SubFolderRelativePath As Variant)
    Dim tempPath As Variant

    'Make Temporary Folder
    tempPath = Environ("Temp") & "\"
    Do While Len(Dir(tempPath, vbDirectory)) > 0
        tempPath = tempPath & "0"
    Loop
    MkDir tempPath

    Dim control As Object
    Set control = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    'Copy Zip Contents to Temporary Folder
    control.Namespace(tempPath).CopyHere control.Namespace(ZipFile).Items

    'Debug.Print tempPath

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Delete Target Folder
        .DeleteFolder tempPath & SubFolderRelativePath
        'Delete Original FIle
        Kill ZipFile

        'First we create an empty zip file: https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/zip-files-using-vba/
        Open ZipFile For Output As #1
        Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
        Close #1

        'Copy the Remaining Items into the new Zip File
        control.Namespace(ZipFile).CopyHere control.Namespace(tempPath).Items
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        'Delete Temporary Folder
        .DeleteFolder tempPath
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for the Mikku and SiddharthRout for there help.

Comment: Impressive @TinMan, I added a bit of explanation on what `.Self.Verbs.Item(4)` means.

Comment: Still looking how to suppress that warning. :(. Or maybe pass on a Yes.

Comment: @SiddharthRout ... Your answer was Informative. Shouldn't have deleted it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was rushing to finish on break.  I'll try to put together a better post soon.  Thanks

Comment: @SiddharthRout I ended up using your suggestion to solve the problem.  Thanks

Comment: @TinMan .... Would you like to ask a new question on how to surpass the warning ? Or should i do it ?

Comment: @Mikku `DeleteZipSubDirectory` does not show a warning.  I'm guessing that you would have to modify the registry to suppress it using the verb high may require admin rights on certain systems with tight security.

Comment: @TinMan .. Yes I understand that. But honestly I wasn't looking for this Method. I was looking for something direct like `.Self.Verbs.Item(4)`. So i think it's worth trying to find an answer on how to suppress Windows Warning.

Comment: I am not convinced that the Delete verb will always be the fifth item in the collection.

Comment: @GSerg I edited my post adding `InVokeVerb("Delete")` as the better method to delete the folder.

Comment: @TinMan Interestingly, `InvokeVerb` [is documented to accept the verb's `Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem-invokeverb#parameters) as returned by [`FolderItemVerb.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitemverb-name). `FolderItemVerb.Name` is localized. In reality, `InvokeVerb` responds to the non-localized name, and does not respond to the localized name.

Comment: @GSerg Then there is no convincing you...lol.   The localization is a great point.  It leads me to believe that using the index would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get [TinMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9912714/tinman)'s original idea to work by setting a WinAPI Timer to click yes in the confirmation dialog. API and TimerProc declarations are for VBA7 onwards.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                                         ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                                        ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, _
                                                        ByVal uElapse As Long, _
                                                        ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

' Delete the specified sub folder from a Zip file.
' Example:
' Call DeleteZipSubFolder("E:\first.zip\first\second")
Sub DeleteZipSubFolder(PathToZipFolder)
  Dim oShell As Object ' Reference: Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation
  
  On Error Resume Next
  
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  
  TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf TimerProc)
  
  oShell.NameSpace(PathToZipFolder).Self.InvokeVerb "Delete"
  
  KillTimer 0, TimerID
  
  Set oShell = Nothing
  
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub

Public Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                     ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, _
                     ByVal dwTime As Long)
                         
  ' Wait for the Shell confirmation dialog to appear
  Sleep 100
  ' Use the Alt+Y shortcut to click the Yes button
  SendKeys "%Y"
  
End Sub
```